# Where is the triangle normal pointing so I can map correctly?

Tags: math, opengl, texture-mapping

Here is what I have so far.
I have a 3D model and I made a triangle mesh. Calculated and applied normals to the model too.
I want to apply different textures into the triangle. I also have the direction vector of all the texture I need.

For mapping, I do this:
I just calculate the Dot product of each triangle normal with the texture direction vector of each texture, and start comparing to see which texture could suitable BASED UPON the calculation of dot product.

But I realised that it is not as straight forward as I thought it was. Because two or more, different triangle could be in almost same orientation in 3D space, meaning one could be facing towards me and the other could be facing opposite direction (maybe parallel but different direction).

I think a better question is how do I use the calculated dot-product to distinguish the face of the triangle so I know I know which image/texture should be used ?

Comment: I think asking this on http://math.stackexchange.com/ would be a better idea. However I cannot suggest it to be put there, maybe you can move it yourself?

Comment: @K_B I am sorry for this. How I do I move it?

Comment: Just create the same question on that forum. Alternatively look at the answer below, it might be the one you were looking for!

Comment: I'm still not really getting what you're up to. Do you want to select a texture for each individual triangle based on which *"texture direction"* is nearest to the direction of the triangle normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the triangles are facing in opposite directions, the normals will also face in opposite directions, and the dot products will have opposite signs. Therefore the dot product gives you enough information to distinguish between the opposite faces. I can't think of a simple test which would give better results than the dot product.

Comment: Let's take a normal (n) that is facing towards me, let say I have the normal of the texture that is looking towards that triangle, (i). If I do "n" dot "i" and "n" dot "n", which result is positive and negative?

As I said before, I am weak at maths.

Comment: The easist way to look at a dot product is this:

a.b = |a||b|cos(x)

where x is the angle between them. Because the magnitudes are unsigned the sign is determined by the cosine alone. cos(x) is positive between -90 and +90 degrees and negative outside that range. Orthogonal vectors have a dot product of zero, vectors pointing in roughly the same direction have positive dot products, opposite direction negative dot products.

In your example, as I understand it the normals n and i are pointing in opposite directions? So the dot product will be negative.

Comment: ohhhhh thank you ... I don't know why I never thought of that.